# R unzip vs system2

Tags: r, asynchronous, unzip

I have a block of code (called by an maple) that unzips hundreds of files and then loads each file into each own table or a family of files into a table. One file exceeded the 4GB, so I can't not longer use R unzip. This is what I did but the script is taking now 5 times longer to complete which is not an option.
The code is part of a function that is being called via "apply". The script is also executed in multiple nodes

I believe that the issue is that the system2 - unzip is running synchronous.
If I remove the stdout, it should run asynchronous, right? But then, it will be unable to load the file as it would not be unzipped.

```
if (file < than 4GB) {
    unzip(zip_file, file_name, exdir=down_dir)
} else
    system2("unzip", args = c("-o", zip_file, file_name, paste0("-d ",     down_dir)), stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE))
}

... code to load file into a table
```

Expected: That the synchronous thread would only apply to that condition, and the remaining files would be processed asynchronous.
Actually: If affected the processing of hundreds of files that are being unzipped via R unzip

Comment: Have you tried `wait=FALSE`? Caution, though, starting 100s of `unzip`s nearly-simultaneously may play havoc with the underlying system. This might be better suited for "regular shell commands", such as `find somepath -name '*.zip' | xargs -P 10 -I {} unzip -d {}.dir {}`, which would max at 10 simultaneous unzips (putting each zipfile into its like-named `somefile.zip.dir/` directory). (I'm assuming access to `find` and `xargs`, both accessible in Git for Windows and every unix-y system that I work with.)

Comment: Thanks! That would be my next step which it can also be accomplished (if I understood it correctly) by not setting stdout and at that point the code is going to be asynchronous. Computational resources in the environment that I am running this code are not an issue. My concern is that it tries to load a file that has not been unzipped yet. I have to test it.

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't mention that ... `wait=FALSE` is ignored if `stdout=TRUE` or `stderr=TRUE`. The side-effect of that is you will not know when (if) it completes nor if there were errors.